# Python multiprocessing managers with context manager and properties

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using the functionality in the `multiprocessing` package to create synchronized shared objects. My objects have both `property` attributes and are also context managers (i.e. have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods).

I've came across a curiosity where I can't make both work at the same time, at least with the recipes I found online, both in python 2 and 3.

Suppose this simple class being registered into a manager:

```
class Obj(object):
    @property
    def a(self): return 1
    def __enter__(self): return self
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kw): pass
```

Normally both won't work because what we need is not exposed:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy
BaseManager.register('Obj', Obj)
m = BaseManager(); m.start();
o = m.Obj()
o.a # AttributeError: 'AutoProxy[Obj]' object has no attribute 'a'
with o: pass # AttributeError: __exit__
```

A solution I have found on SO that uses a custom proxy instead of `AutoProxy` works for the property but not the context manager (no matter if `__enter__` and `__exit__` is exposed this way or not):

```
class MyProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ['__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', 'a', '__enter__', '__exit__']
BaseManager.register('Obj', Obj, MyProxy)
m = BaseManager(); m.start();
o = m.Obj()
o.a # outputs 1
with o: pass # AttributeError: __exit__
```

I can make the context manager alone work by using the `exposed` keyword while registering:

```
BaseManager.register('Obj', Obj, exposed=['__enter__', '__exit__'])
m = BaseManager(); m.start();
o = m.Obj()
with o: pass # works
```

But if I also add the stuff for the property I get a max recursion error:

```
BaseManager.register('Obj', Obj, exposed=['__enter__', '__exit__', '__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', 'a'])
m = BaseManager(); m.start();
o = m.Obj() # RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

If I leave out `__getattribute__` and friends I see `a` as a bound method which tries to call the property value instead of the method itself, so that doesn't work either.

I have tried to mix and match in every way I could think of and couldn't find a solution. Is there a way of doing this or maybe this is a bug in the lib?

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that the way these managers are implemented is focused in controlling the access to shared data in then, in the form of Attributes. They won't do great in dealing with other Python features such as properties, or "dunder" methods that depend on the object state, like `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

It would certainly be possible to get to specific workarounds for each needed feature, by means of subclassing the Proxy object, until one would get each to work - but the result of that would never be bullet-proof for all corner cases, much less for all Python class features.

So, I think that in this case the best you do is to create a simple- data-only class!  One that just uses plain attributes - no properties, no descriptors, no attribute-access customization - just a plain data class whose instances will hold the *data* you need to share. Actually, you may not even need such a class, since the managers module provide a Synced dictionary type - just use that,

And then you create a second class where you build this intelligence you need. This second classes will have getters and setters and properties, and can implement the context protocol, and any dunder method you like, **and** get hold of an associated instance of the data class. All the intelligence in the methods and properties can make use of the data in this instance. Actually, you might just use a `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict` syncronized dictionary to hold your data.

Then, if you make this associated data class  managed, it will work in a straightforward and simple way, and, in each process, you build the "smart class" wrapping it.

Your code snippets don't give examples on how you pass your objetcs from one process to the other - I hope you are aware that by calling BaseManager.Obj() you get new, local, instances of your classes anyway - you have to get a Queue to share your objects cross-process, regardless of the managers.

The proof of concept bellow shows an example of what I mean.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

class MySpecialClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.data["a"]

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
        pass


def worker(data):
    obj = MySpecialClass(data)
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        obj.data[i] = i ** 2

def main():
    m = SyncManager()
    m.start()
    data = m.dict()

    server_obj = MySpecialClass(data)

    p = Process(target=worker, args=(data,))
    p.start()
    for i in range(22):
        print(server_obj.data)
        time.sleep(.5)
    p.join()


main()
```

Keep in mind that if you need to coordinate your context-blocks across processes, due to some resources, you can pass manager.Lock() objects around as easily as the data dictionary above - even as a value in the dictionary - and it would then be ready to use inside the object's `__enter__` method.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, using composition with a sync dict is a nice approach. However I'm refactoring a medium-to-large codebase which needs to synchronize one of its main classes so refactoring this way can be quite an undertaking... But you did give me another idea with trying to implement more  in the proxy object subclass